# Would these two fonts be different enough from each other for one not to be cosidered a copyright violation of the other one?

Tags: fonts, copyright

[image: 9 compared to 9]

Not sure of the legal way of wording this; but here is my best guess. Wondering if design wise if these two fonts are different enough from each other as not to violate copyright law in the sense of the actual designs and differences between them.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Unfortunatley I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a legal question. These are off-topic here. Sorry about that.  You should contact your lawyer instead.

Comment: It also depends whether one font is derived from the other, or both are derived from a common [unweathered] source; or they are completely independent. You do need a copyright lawyer who will need to be in possession of all the facts.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - also there are differences in how copyright law is interpreted as far as  fonts are concerned, depending on one's location in the world.